# LinearLayout - Vertically not align

Tags: android, button, android-linearlayout

I got a problem with LinearLayout on Android. I have four buttons. Each button has a fixed size, but the text can vary in length.

My problem is that they are not align with the top of each. They seen to be align with the top of the text inside of each botton which change depending on the number of line there is inside the button (See picture).

Also, I want to keep using LinearLayout as I will eventually use code will add buttons based on data from a database.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">
       <LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">
           <Button android:text="Line1 Line2" android:textSize="30dp" android:layout_width="160dp" android:layout_height="120dp"></Button>
           <Button android:text="Line1 Line2 Line3" android:textSize="30dp" android:layout_width="160dp" android:layout_height="120dp"></Button>
           <Button android:text="Line1" android:textSize="30dp" android:layout_width="160dp" android:layout_height="120dp"></Button>
           <Button android:text="Line1" android:textSize="30dp" android:layout_width="160dp" android:layout_height="120dp"></Button>
       </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

[image: http://i.imgur.com/0Kj8h.png]

## **EDIT: ANSWER (Can't answer my own question):**

Ok, I just found the answer by myself.
You have to add android:baselineAligned="false" to LinearLayout or any other similar control that could show the same behavior.

You can also fix this in the UI designer using the button called "Toggle Baseline Alignment".

So the resulting code is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">
       <LinearLayout android:baselineAligned="false" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">
           <Button android:text="Line1 Line2" android:textSize="30dp" android:layout_width="160dp" android:layout_height="120dp"></Button>
           <Button android:text="Line1 Line2 Line3" android:textSize="30dp" android:layout_width="160dp" android:layout_height="120dp"></Button>
           <Button android:text="Line1" android:textSize="30dp" android:layout_width="160dp" android:layout_height="120dp"></Button>
           <Button android:text="Line1" android:textSize="30dp" android:layout_width="160dp" android:layout_height="120dp"></Button>
       </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip about android:baselineAligned="false", it fixed my issue too :-)

Answer (score 1):

its better to use RelativeLayout for such type of alignment, as RelativeLayout's concept says that it "reference" of a control

Answer (score 0):

Well your second linear layout is whats creating the trouble I guess for u, just remove that

Comment: I need to keep it as there will be other stuff around it such as a title, but good point.

Answer (score 0):

You can use TableLayout instead of Your Second LinearLayout.And add a TableRow inside the TableLayout and in the row add four buttons

Comment: TableLayout does the same if you put all your item in the same cell. Also, as I said I want to stay with LinearLayout because I will eventually add an unknown number of button by code.
I don't know what's going to be show in those button, so I need to keep a simple way to display them as a flow. Also, it will automatically adjust when the screen rotate.