# Is it possible to list what permissions other apps have?

Tags: android

I'm working on a security app and I  would like to warn users which applications have dangerous permissions

Is there a way to do this on Android?

Answer (score -1):

Get List of installed packages

```
List<PackageInfo> installedPackages = context.getPackageManager()
                    .getInstalledPackages(PackageManager.GET_PERMISSIONS);
```

Fetch permission of installed packages

```
for (int i = 0; i < installedPackages.size(); i++) {
        PackageInfo packageInfo = installedPackages.get(i);

        FeatureInfo[] packageFeature = packageInfo.reqFeatures;
        PermissionInfo[] packagePermission = packageInfo.permissions;
```

}

Comment: I think you answered the wrong question. Were you looking for [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36658862/odd-behavior-of-button-in-linear-layout-that-has-one-line-of-text-instead-of-two)?

Comment: Why downvote ? see the edit.

Comment: I would guess that it's because you had initially posted a completely irrelevant answer.

Comment: First answer was a mistake and edit is because I already have a project on GitHub which does what you are trying to do https://github.com/hiteshsahu/Android-App-Data-Usage-Monitor

Comment: Tell me how it is wrong ?